# SQL DECIMAL to Java Number

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a database (MySQL 5.6 if it matters) in which I would like to store numeric values that will usually, but not always, be integers. Right now I have a `DECIMAL(10, 3)` column which seems to be working well. What I'm looking for is a method I know doesn't exist in native JDBC, but would be something like:

```
public Number ResultSet.getNumber()
```

which would return me a `Long` (or maybe even `Integer`) if the underlying SQL value is actually an integer, and a `Double` otherwise. Is there some way to get an equivalent result from an SQL DECIMAL column in JDBC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended Java mapping for SQL DECIMAL and NUMERIC values is BigDecimal:

```
ResultSet.getBigDecimal()
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 4):

You can get decimal value from the table and convert it into Double as:

```
BigDecimal res = ResultSet.getBigDecimal();
```

Comment: Why you get it as BigDecimal and then you convert it to double? Use directly ResultSet.getDouble() eventually.

Comment: Correct!. Just to convert it into a double value I showed it.